# Video file being accessed twice on mobile device

Tags: html, video, mobile

I'm working on my own DRM solution for video content. I'm verifying each access to the actual video file. So video.mp4 is actually video.php which then streams orig_vid.mp4 into a `<video>` element.

It works fine and all – except on mobile! Mobile seems to access the video file two times, making the second request unverifiable.

Before the video is played (autoplay not possible on mobile) it accesses the file once, probably to get headers, etc. Then another request is coming throug, once we hit the play button (as expected), but after that, there's another request, and I can't figure out why or how to validate this request.

If at least I know the pattern behind the requests, I could build my script so it accommodates those. But to me right now the 2 requests seem random...

Any idea or explanation why that is or what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Are there **Cache-Control**, **Date** and **Expires** headers properly set?

Comment: To my knowledge they are not. Can you specify please? The headers of which request should be set, and why? Thanks for the answer. :)